# Regex match between word and -

Tags: regex, expression

Could you please please help me a bit? I am trying to get via regular expression the following

It should scan for "cat = " and should return like this

```
for
bla bla cat =  322 + 50 - 20 =  302 euro
returns 50

bla bla cats =  322 + 50 - 20 =  302 euro
returns nothing

bla bla cat =  322  - 20 =  302 euro
returns nothing
```

Comment: So why should the third line not work? What's different about the pattern?

Comment: You should specify the language..

Answer (score 0):

```
cat\s*=.+\+(.+)-
```

`\s*` optional whitspace
`.+\+` is `.+` plus `+` but escaped with `\` because `.++` has different meaning

[code example](http://rubular.com/r/oiKj6Sds5I)